# Creating a jQuery full-width slider with controllers

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm searching a way to create full-width slider like here: www.browar-olbracht.pl - slider in the header. This one is from free joomla template. (mod_slider). I'm interested in creating sth like this but in personal project without joomla/wordpress etc. Without cms.
I have found a lot of sliders but any full-width and with controllers like in the page above. I'm rather a beginner in jQuery so my question is - is there an already prepared script or maybe someone of the experienced users can tell me how to create sth similar or just to convert existing one ?

P.

Answer (score 1):

That slider is not responsive to browser screen sizes. If you were to mimic that, some of your important slider controls will get chopped off the page and not appear again until the screen is wide enough to show them.

Here are 3 sliders that will allow you to do a full width slide with some slight adjustments to their CSS files.

The Easy Slider
http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/

The PlusSlider
http://css-plus.com/examples/plugins/PlusSlider/

ResponsiveSlides.js 
http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/

Comment: Yes, as I can see it's not exactly fullwdith which depends on screen resolution but rather a very wide resolution image . But I'll try to use one of these three. Placing controllers like in the example (browar-olbracht.pl) is only a CSS styling, yes ? So the conversion of one of these three will help me to achieve the effect from the example ?

Comment: Yes I guarantee you can do it with some CSS practice and maybe decent understanding of creating .png images.